# AOP Performance issue

Tags: aspectj, spring-aop

Below code is taking more time decreasing overall application performance.

```
 @Aspect
 @Component
 public class LoggingHandler {

/**
 * Logger initialization.
 *
 */
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingHandler.class);

/**
 * Around advise for SlingAdapterImpl.
 * @param pjp joinPoint
 * @return response
 * @throws Throwable exception
 */
@Around("execution(* com.abcd.oicp.storage.client.impl.SlingAdapterImpl.*(..))")
public Object logAroundAllMethods(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

    long startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

    Object obj = null;
    try {
        obj = pjp.proceed();
    } finally {
        logger.info("Method={} Time taken={} micro secs", pjp.getSignature().getName(),
                    (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMicros(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startTime)));
    }


    return obj;
 }
}
```

In JMeter, It is consuming ~1.5sec. WHY?

**Is Time converting from milli seconds to micro seconds a
performance issue.**

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use `System.nanoTime()` or `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead of `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()`